# Como hacer 2 consulta en una misma query?

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo una BBDD en la que guardo todas las visitas diarias a un monton de webs,
los campos de la tabla day son name, nvisit y date

Quiero hacer una comparativa entre las visitas de anteayer y las de ayer por lo que el resultado a mostrar deberían ser 3 columnas. nombre,  anteayer y  ayer

He probado con esta consulta pero me lo muestra todo en 2 columnas

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT name as nombre, nvisit as anteayer
    from day
    WHERE date < CURDATE() -1 and date > CURDATE() -2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT name as nombre, nvisit as ayer
    from day
    where date < CURDATE() and date > CURDATE() -1
    GROUP by name
    )
    day
```

Que puedo hacer para resolver este problema??

Comment: Estas confundiendo filas con columnas, debes dominar los términos correctos para que se te entienda mejor, es solo una observación que quería hacerte

Comment: Gracias por tu observacion.

Comment: Edite tu pregunta y corregí lo de las filas por columnas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El operador que debes usar es `JOIN` no `UNION`, por eso te salen 2 columnas en vez de 3. Prueba así:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT `name`,SUM(nvisit) anteayer FROM `day`
      WHERE date < CURDATE() -1 and date > CURDATE() -2
      GROUP BY 1                
  ) anteayer JOIN (
    SELECT `name`,SUM(nvisit) ayer FROM `day`
      WHERE date < CURDATE() and date > CURDATE() -1
      GROUP BY 1
  ) ayer USING(`name`);
```

Incluyo el dataset para las pruebas:

```
CREATE TABLE `day`(
  `name` varchar(31),
  nvisit int,
  `date` date
  );
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto!
Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)